# ERROR : javascript.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

Fala pessoal, tudo bem?
é o seguinte, tenho dois forms para cadastro, mas só quero que o segundo apareça quando for clicado em próximo, no primeiro form coloco via css um visibility= visible e no segundo form um visibility = hidden, e no javascript quando clicar em próximo eu altero os valores do visibility, mas só funciona para o primeiro form, ele altera para hidden mas o segundo não altera para visible e apresenta esse erro : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null**

Segue prints:

HTML:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JS :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Serei grato pela ajuda!!

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: De qualquer forma, `cadastro2` é uma classe e não um id, por isso `getElementById` não encontra o elemento

Comment: obrigado!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu segundo **document.getElementById** você está buscando por ID mas na verdade é uma classe. Mude para **document.querySelector(".cadastro2")** e veja se funciona.

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO, JUNIOR. não tinha percebido isso. Muito obrigado mesmo.